# How is standard inner product on $\mathbb R^n$ nondegenerate?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, bilinear-form

A bilinear form $B: V \times V \to \mathbb R$ is nondegenerate if the map $V \to V^*$ defined by $v \mapsto B(v,-)$ is injective for all $v \in V$.

---

Take $V= \mathbb R^2$ and take $B$ to be the standard inner product on $\mathbb R^2$.

Take $v=(1,0)$. Then $B((1,0), (0,1))=1 \cdot 0 +0 \cdot 1 =0$. But then the map $B((1,0),-)$ is not injective since $(0,1) \mapsto 0$ but $(0,1) \ne (0,0)$.

**What is wrong here?**

Comment: It's not about $B(v,\cdot)$ for a fixed $v$ but about $v\mapsto B(v,\cdot)$. In the case of the standard inner product, let $B(v,\cdot) = B(w,\cdot)$. Then $B(v,x) = B(w,x)$ for all $x$. So, $B(v-w,x) = 0$ for all $x$. But this can only happen if $v-w=0$.

Comment: You tested the injectivity of the map $w\mapsto B(v,w)$, not the map $v\mapsto B(v,-)$. Assume that $B(v,-)$ is the zero functional of $V^*$. This means that for all $w\in V$ you have $B(v,w)=0$. In particular $0=B(v,v)=\|v\|^2$. Therefore, $v=0$.

Comment: Ahh, I see now what I did wrong. Thanks.